# National instruments(ni) required kernel modules loaded but still getting error

Tags: windows, docker, linux-kernel, wsl-2, rocky-os

In visual studio code, in my java project repository, I created a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM rocky-9-wsl2kernel-ni:latest

RUN dnf install -y rpm-build gcc make vim git wget \
   openssh-server bc flex bison openssl-devel elfutils-libelf-devel \
   rsync kmod ncurses-devel pkg-config chkconfig dwarves java-17-openjdk-devel

EXPOSE 5025
```

In the vscode command palette, I ran a command that auto created a `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file. I added code to it. The following is the content of my `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file:

```
{
   "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
   "build": {
      // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
      "context": "..",
      // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
      "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
   },
   "runArgs": [
      "--net",
      "host",
      "--env",
      "DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0",
      "--privileged",
      "--cap-add=ALL"
   ],
   "customizations": {
      "vscode": {
         "extensions": [
            "vscjava.vscode-java-pack",
            "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

In the vscode command palette, I ran the command `Dev Containers: Rebuild Without Cache and Reopen in Container`. Inside the container built from `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`, I ran the following commands sequentially which I got from the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/community/content/wsl-user-msft-kernel-v6 : `cd /usr/src/kernels`, `git clone https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git --depth=1 -b linux-msft-wsl-6.1.y`, `cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel`, `make -j$(nproc) KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl`, `make modules_install headers_install`, `make defconfig`. I then pulled up a windows powershell and ran the command `docker cp 90a6f4002eee8c8c2733d70cb997a0817f88471291afa35b3fa05ce6a5ca4277:/usr/src/kernels/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/arch/x86/boot/bzImage /Users/eliam.calvo`. In that same windows powershell I ran the command `docker commit 90a6f4002eee8c8c2733d70cb997a0817f88471291afa35b3fa05ce6a5ca4277 rocky-9-wsl2kernel:latest` next. On my windows machine, I then went to C:\Users\eliam.calvo and created the file `.wslconfig` with the following content:

```
[wsl2]
kernel=C:\\Users\\eliam.calvo\\bzImage
```

I then closed the connection to the dev container and then pulled up a windows powershell as administrator and ran the command `wsl --shutdown`.

I then changed my `Dockerfile` to the following:

```
FROM rocky-9-wsl2kernel:latest

EXPOSE 5025
```

I then ran the command `Dev Containers: Reopen in Container` in the vscode command palette. I then ran the command `docker cp /Users/eliam.calvo/Desktop/NILinux2024Q1DeviceDrivers/NILinux2024Q1DeviceDrivers/ni-rhel9-drivers-2024Q1.rpm e156acaa0815b2df90aa79a467f2df26775f19d7db67ec50f30f73df54ba86e7:/home` in a windows powershell which I got the rpm from https://www.ni.com/en/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-linux-device-drivers.html#521765. Then, inside the dev container terminal, I ran the following command sequentially which I basically followed from https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/ni-platform-on-linux-desktop/page/installing-ni-products-red-hat-enterprise-linux.html : `dnf install -y /home/ni-rhel9-drivers-2024Q1.rpm`, `dnf install -y ni-visa`, `rm -rf /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64`, `dnf install -y ni-hwcfg-utility`, and `dkms autoinstall`. Then, in a windows powershell, I ran the command `docker commit e156acaa0815b2df90aa79a467f2df26775f19d7db67ec50f30f73df54ba86e7 rocky-9-wsl2kernel-ni:latest`. I then closed the remote connection. I then changed my `Dockerfile` to the following:

```
FROM rocky-9-wsl2kernel-ni:latest

EXPOSE 5025
```

I then opened a dev container in vscode by running the command `Dev Containers: Reopen in Container` in the vscode command palette. By the way, the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` has remained the same this whole time. Then, in the terminal inside my dev container, I run the command `modprobe -v nipalk` and `insmod /usr/lib/modules/6.1.21.2-microsoft-standard-WSL2+/extra/NiViPciK.ko` to insert the required kernel modules in. Inside my Java repository inside the dev container, I run my Java application. When the Java application executes the line `JVisaLibrary.viOpenDefaultRM(NativeLongByReference arg0)`, my application closes abruptly. This is what the terminal inside that docker container looks like:

```
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
NiViPciK               77824  0
nipalk                897024  1 NiViPciK
nikal                 102400  1 nipalk
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]#  cd /workspaces/msda-test ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.10.0.7-2.el9.x86_64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:34353 @/tmp/cp_aevhl9otyttw9qr0cmd0fl9ar.argfile com.bluehalo.msda.cca.tester.Tester 
libnipalu.so failed to initialize
Verify that nipalk.ko is built and loaded.
Aborted
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]#
```

As you can see, I check to see if the modules are loaded in yet before running my java application. Then after the application is ran, i get the error from the terminal output above. I’m not sure what else to try.

Comment: Try using `strace` to trace system calls. Check the results of system calls just before the "libbipalu.so failed to initialize" message is written. Perhaps it is trying to open a nonexistent device file or something.

Comment: @ian-abbott I ran the application with strace and found out that the /dev/nipalk device was not created. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the device node `/dev/nipalk` wasn't created automatically. A work around that I did was first do a `grep nikal /proc/devices` to find the major device number assigned to the nikal module. Then I did a `mknod /dev/nipalk c major_number minor_number`. Replace `major_number` with the number you got from the output of `grep nikal /proc/devices` and `minor_number` with `0`, assuming that is the first created device for `nikal` that the `nikal` driver manages. The following is my terminal output as an example.

```
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]# grep nikal /proc/devices
241 nikal
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]# mknod /dev/nipalk c 241 0
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]# ls -l /dev/nipalk
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 241, 0 Feb 20 22:44 /dev/nipalk
[root@docker-desktop msda-test]#
```

I don't know why the device wasn't created automatically though whenever I loaded the module into the kernel. Also, I don't know why I have to load in the modules manually either. In a normal installation, all I have to do is follow the steps from https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/ni-platform-on-linux-desktop/page/installing-ni-products-red-hat-enterprise-linux.html .